# How can I restore the missing Auto-save toggle in Microsoft Office on MacOS after reinstalling OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, onedrive, autosave

I had to reformate my macbook and reinstall OneDrive. After reinstalling when I opened a microsoft office file (word, excel or pp) the autosave toggle disappeared.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

[image: This is before reinstalling OneDrive]

[image: This is after reinstalling OneDrive]

I tried to fix this by reinstalling microsoft office apps and also tried to reinstall OneDrive but still didn't get the autosave toggle back.

Comment: Are the Microsoft Office applications signed in to the Microsoft account?

Comment: Have you changed the Office versions? Generally, Microsoft 365 Apps have autosave function.